# S3Client gives fatal error - Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient' not found

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have aws sdk in current directory. I have included sdk in file like this..

```
include("Aws/S3/S3Client.php");

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class myClass{

}
```

It gives me fatal error like..

```
Fatal error: Class 'Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient' not found in /somePath/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 117
```

Please help.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but did you happen to find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem and just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all these error while sending request or getting response from AWS, set up AWS SDK using http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/php/, or use

```bash
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-php-sample.git
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

By installing AWS SDK in this way, you'll get a file at `vendor/autoload.php`

It'll take care of all the required files into the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and wasn't able to find an answer anywhere. So, in case anyone has the same problem in the future, for me it was simply a matter of using a version of AWS SDK that was incompatible with my PHP version.

Once I upgraded my server's PHP version it all worked fine.